# Selenium and TestNG all test in one browser

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have abstract class, where initialize webdriver. All classes with the implementation of the tests are inherited from him. I want to reduce the time of test, open a browser for all tests.

```
class AbstractClassCase {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass    
    @Parameters({"webDriver", "applicationHost", "applicationPort", "driverHost", "driverPort",  "username", "password"})
    public void setUp(
        String webDriverIdentifier,
        String applicationHost,
        @Optional String applicationPort,
        @Optional String driverHost,
        @Optional String driverPort,
        @Optional String username,
        @Optional String password){      

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("localhost");
        login(username, password)

    }

    @AfterСlass
    public void tearDown() {   
        driver.quite();
    }     

}

public class TestButton extends AbstractClassCase {
    @Test
    public void testClickButtonNo() {
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("button-no"));
        button.click();
        WebElement status = driver.findElement(By.id("button-status"));
        Assert.assertEqual("Cancel", status.getText());
   }
}
```

and other test class in the same spirit.

How can I reconfigure this class, so that the browser opened once?

Comment: So you want to open the browser once, run all tests and then close it.. instead of opening the browser for each test.. right?

Comment: Yes, it is. Now opens before each test

Comment: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp - "As a test suite starts in your favorite language, the following happens:

The client/driver establishes a connection with the selenium-RC server.
Selenium RC server launches a browser (or reuses an old one) with a URL that will load Selenium-Core in the web page."

Comment: Try to verify if driver is already created if (driver == null) { drvier = new FireFoxDrvier()} else he will use existing driver and remove afterClass, it will close your browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to Open Browser at the start once and run all the methods and then close it.

There are 2 steps i would recommend to follow.

***Step 1***:
Include browser invocation code in methods with ***@BeforeSuite*** && ***@AfterSuite*** for closing the browser/driversession. This makes sure these tests are run once before and after test suite.

```
protected static WebDriver Browser_Session;

@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite() {
    Browser_Session=new FirefoxDriver();
    Browser_Session.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

@AfterSuite
public void afterSuite() {
    Browser_Session.quit();
}
```

***Step2*** : Open testng.xml and include all such classes (test methods) under a single Suite, Thus making sure the browser (via Selenium) is invoked first and then rest all methods are run in the same browser.
[image]

Here "***Class Init***" contains Browser Initiating code and ClassA & ClassB are subclassess of Init.

Hope this helps

Comment: Is not that the NullPointerException occurred during the passage of the second test? Have you declared WebDriver variable as static?

Comment: @martinixs: Yeah i have declared WebDriver as Static,Protected and it worked without any exception mentioned. I have updated  code block and TestNG.xml screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run all test in one instance, i wrote my own WebDriverFactory so here is some examples for help:

```
    public static WebDriver getDriver(){
       if (driver == null) {
            return new FireFoxDriver();
        } else {
          return driver;
        }
   }
```

Now remove AfterClass and add this to your class it will shutdown your browser in the end

```
static {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    dismissDriver();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
}

 public static void dismissDriver() {
        if (driver != null) {
            try {
                driver.quit();
                driver = null;
            } catch (Throwable t) {
            }
        }
    }
```